# How to update dynamically of multiple rows in one table using Graphql

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am new to graphql hasura and i'm having this issue how to update multiple rows in one table, because usually i update only one row per table.

i want to update multiple rows in a dynamic way

I have for example existing rows data.

```
id: 1, name: 'rosie', age: 12
id: 2, name: 'jane', age: 20
id: 3, name: 'rafaela', age: 25
```

and I want to edit the 2 rows only.

```
id: 1, name: 'rosie update', age: 12
id: 2, name: 'jane update', age: 21
```

i have an array of users.
it can be 1 or more than 1 users that will be updated.

```
const users = [
{id: 1, name: 'rosie update', age: 12}.
{id: 2, name: 'jane update', age: 21}
];

mutation update_article {
  update_user(
    where: {id: {_eq: users[0].id}},
    _set: {
      name: users[0].name,
      age: users[0].age
   }
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

expected output should be:

want to have mutation code in dynamic way not static.

```
id: 1, name: 'rosie update', age: 12
id: 2, name: 'jane update', age: 21
id: 3, name: 'rafaela', age: 25
```

Comment: I have the same issue @rj.learn did you found the solution pls share

Answer (score 20):

Reading the documentation [mutation](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/graphql-api/mutation.html), you could use `insert` instead of `update` that can handle multiple objects managing the conflict behaviour.

In your example the mutation could be done with:

```
mutation update_article {
  insert_user(objects: [
         {id: 1, name: "rosie update", age: 12},
         {id: 2, name: "jane update", age: 21}
      ],
      on_conflict: {
        constraint: user_id_key,
        update_columns: [name, age]
      }
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

As `id` values already exist, it will update fields `name` and `age`.

Comment: This will only work if the user has id-insert permissions (which she shouldn't). Handling primary keys is the job of the database.

Answer (score 5):

**Run multiple updates with different conditions** (V2.10.0)

1. https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/releases/tag/v2.10.0
2. https://hasura.io/docs/latest/mutations/postgres/update/#multiple-updates

```
mutation update_many_articles {
  update_article_many (
    updates: [
      {
        where: {rating: {_lte: 1}},
        _set: {is_published: false}
      },
      {
       where: {rating: {_gte: 4}},
        _set: {is_published: true}
      }
    ]
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```